# from which file code is coming

Tags: component

I am using Joomla! for the very first time. I need to make some chamges in this [link](http://www.totallyweb.com.au/icon/news/company-announcements.html)

I do not  know from where it is coming. Can anyody give me idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The entries are coming from a custom component named `iconenergy` as you can see if you click on the 2013 list link `?option=com_iconenergy&Itemid=74&date=2013`. You can probably add new entries or edit existing ones from the backend menu (...com.au/icon/administrator) of your joomla installation under the dropdown `components`.

Comment: i got it thanks.. but when i try here is empty..

Comment: You mean there is no menu entry? or you click and you have a blank page?

Comment: Hello World administration

Comment: when i click this one is coming. i check code . view.php file only have this Hello World administration

Comment: Then I think the best way to go, as it is a custom component and I don't know the structure of it, is to check the files of the frontent folder located in `components/com_iconenergy` and see there from where it fetches the items in the list, or if there is a form. For a form or edit view you can check also the backend directory `administrator/components`. You'll have to try to find it this way unfortunately.